# Definitive if check

Tags: c, if-statement

Consider this kind of if-statment in a function:

```
int Foo( void )
{
    if ( HostCPUInfo::IsSSE3Supported() )
        // SSE3 intrinsic
    else
        // C code
}
```

I check during the runtime if SSE3 instructions are supported by the host CPU to permit the use of faster intrinsic. But, as I doubt the the return of  HostCPUInfo::IsSSE3Supported() is going to change during the life of my program, is there a way to only make this kind of checks once (maybe during the initialization) ?

Comment: @IrrationalPerson It'd help to explain what aspect you find confusing. The entire thing seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Would a separate binary for SSE3 machines be an even better solution?

Comment: @DevSolar - a tiny (insignificant) bit more efficient, at the expense of far less flexible. You will need different binaries for each platform variations instead of for each platforms.

Comment: Is this really C? The `::` smells like C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function pointer that is initialized to a function that performs the test. This way, you don't have to call a special initialization function before using `foo()`:

```
int foo_init (void);
int foo1 (void);
int foo2 (void);

int (*Foo) (void) = foo_init;

int foo_init (void)
{
  Foo = (HostCPUInfo::IsSSE3Supported() ? foo1 : foo2);
  return Foo();
}

...

int main (void)
{
  Foo();

  ...
}
```

This *might* have implications for performance if the compiler is unable to inline the `foo` functions.

Comment: Function pointers are already covered in the already accepted answer from an hour ago. Why repeating?

Comment: @ddriver: Because my version is a little more clever, and there wasn't an accepted answer by the time I wrote it.

Comment: A bit simpler and easier to understand (at least, for me) than the cnicutar's answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way with function pointers:

```
int (*foo)() = synthetic_foo;

void init() {
    if (HostCPUInfo::IsSSE3Supported()) {
        foo = sse3_foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `HostCPUInfo::IsSSE3Supported()` once before entering `Foo` and set some boolean depending on the return value.

Then in `Foo` check only that boolean, which will always remain the same regardless of whether the return value of `HostCPUInfo::IsSSE3Supported()` changes.